# Retrieve data form two or more tables by lambda expression

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

I have two tables, `Entity` and `Payment`.

`Entity` table:

```
EntityID   EntityName  Country  Currency
----------------------------------------
1          xyz         cou1      cur1
2          abc         cou2      cur2
3          efg         cou1      cur1
```

`Payment` table:

```
 PaymentID   Amount  EntityID   
 -----------------------------
    1          1000   1
    2          3000   2
    3          1000   1
```

I want to get sum of amount of `Entity` with respect to `currency` like

```
currency   Amount
-----------------
cur1       2000
cur2       3000
```

My code

```
var data = db.Payment.GroupBy(x => x.Entity.Currency);
```

With this code I can get data which is group by currency, but I can't sum it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean you want something like: `var sums = data.Select(grp => new { Currency = grp.Key, Sum = grp.Sum(p => p.Amount) });`?

Comment: can you give me a full answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you have defined two classes in your data context:

```
class Entitiy
{
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public string EntityName { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Currency { get; set; }
}

class Payment
{
    public int PaymentID { get; set; }
    public double Amount { get; set; }
    public int EntityID { get; set; }
    public Entitiy Entity { get; set; }
}
```

And later in code you have created a database context, which can be simulated by this:

```
var db = new { Payment = new Payment[0] };
```

Then you use it with *your* code above:

```
var data = db.Payment.GroupBy(x => x.Entity.Currency);
```

And to answer your question how you sum each currency, I suggest this:

```
var sums = data.Select(grp => new { 
    Currency = grp.Key, 
    Sum = grp.Sum(p => p.Amount) 
});
```

Now you have an enumeration of currencies and their respective sums.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
var sum = from p in db.Payment
      from e in db.Entity.Where(e=>e.EntityID == p.EntityID).DefaultIfEmpty()
      group e by e.Currency into Entities
      select new
      {
        currency = Entities.Key,
        Amount = Entities.Sum(s=>s.Amount)  
      };
```